# input[type="submit"] in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

how to do this:

```
input[type="submit"] {
   color:green;
}
```

in jQuery?

```
$('input[type="submit"]').css("color","green");
```

is not working :|

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/JRMhM/

Comment: This should work, however you can try [`:submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/) selector

Comment: I recommend to read the [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery) to get you started: *"As almost everything we do when using jQuery reads or manipulates the document object model (DOM), we need to make sure that we start adding events etc. as soon as the DOM is ready. To do this, we register a ready event for the document."*. Then familiarise yourself with the API by reading http://api.jquery.com/.

Comment: **instead of downvoting , just suggest to close this question as too localized. Is it that hard to remember ? he is new here**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Probably because it is triggering before jQuery is "ready". Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').css("color","green");
});
```

Comment: If you want to have access to the event, use `$(document).ready(function(event) {});` instead of `$(function() {});` I found my version more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Use a simple css instead of javascript

```
input[type="submit"]{
        color: green;
        cursor: pointer;
        font: bold 12px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

But the jquery must load it before this

You can also do this by adding the id or class in submit

```
 $('#submit_id/.submit_class').css("color","green");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

It may be that your original code is working, but since the page re-loads normally when you click on a submit button in a form, that action is preventing you from seeing your change.

Comment: This is a good example of why you want to use `.someThing(function(event) {})` to have access on the event itself.